# In in-cell edit mode, kendo (sortable) grid values do not update when clicking a different row

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In in-cell edit mode, grid values do not update when clicking a different row.  The update is only triggered when the user hits enter, when clicking outside of the grid, OR by tabbing/clicking to another cell in the same row.  The other examples I've seen don't have this behavior so I'm wondering what I might be doing wrong.  This has been an issue for sometime now and it has to be fixed before going live.

I have been able to duplicate the issue in an isolated state.  Implementing drag and drop reordering (Kendo Sortable) seems to cause this behavior.  Again, the behavior is when you are in an editor, change the value in the editor and click an editor in a different row - you will notice that the value doesn't update.  Is this a documented bug?  What is your suggested workaround?

Here is a jsfiddle demonstrating the issue:
    https://jsfiddle.net/bhr7Lmpy/1/

`<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/bhr7Lmpy/1/embed/"></script>`

The Telerik Team responded here:

https://www.telerik.com/forums/in-in-cell-edit-mode-grid-values-do-not-update-when-i-click-a-different-row#aIdr3qwkX0aJnnNY9irSJg

Comment: The problem is coming from the function `generateSortableGrid()`. If you comment it out in the `$(document).ready()` the grid will act normally. Maybe there is another way to make the grid sortable?

Comment: Dragging and dropping is a project requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to put a focusout event on the grid cell that programatically presses the enter key or clicks the save button.